# Splitting Pandas Dataframe with groupby and last

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am working with a pandas dataframe where i want to group by one column, grab the last row of each group (creating a new dataframe), and then drop those rows from the original.

I've done a lot of reading and testing, and it seems that I can't do that as easily as I'd hoped. I can do a kludgy solution, but it seems inefficient and, well, kludgy.

Here's pseudocode for what I wanted to do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame 
last_lines = df.groupby('id').last()
df.drop(last_lines.index)
```

creating the last_lines dataframe is fine, it's dropping those rows from the original df that's an issue. the problem is that the original index (from df) is disconnected when last_lines is created.  i looked at filter and transform, but neither seems to address this problem. is there a good way to split the dataframe into two pieces based on position?

my kludge solution is to iterate over the group iterator and create a list of indexes, then drop those.

```
grouped = df.groupby('id')
idx_to_remove = []
for _, group in grouped:
    idx_to_remove.append(group.tail(1).index[0])
df.drop(idx_to_remove)
```

Better suggestions?

Comment: I gave an answer below, but I'm not sure what you mean about splitting the DataFrame.  It seems you're just trying to drop individual rows, not split.

Comment: could be a language issue... i want to end up with two dataframes, the join of which is the full original dataframe... so, to me that is splitting. i was doing it in two steps... creating the first one was easy.. it was the dropping part that i was having issues with.. so that's why i focused on that. thanks again for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `.reset_index()` first, you'll get the index as a column and you can use `.last()` on that to get the indices you want.

```
last_lines = df.reset_index().groupby('A').index.last()
df.drop(last_lines)
```

Here the index is accessed as `.index` because "index" is the default name given to this column when you use `reset_index`.  If your index has a name, you'll use that instead.

You can also "manually" grab the last index by using `.apply()`:

```
last_lines = d.groupby('A').apply(lambda g: g.index[-1])
```

You'll probably have to do it this way if you're using a MultiIndex (since in that case using `.reset_index()` would add multiple columns that can't easily be combined back into indices to drop).

Comment: Thanks. I had tried reset_index, but _after_, not before. this worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1, :])
```

Comment: thanks. this also worked. just to add comment for any future reader, this created a multi-index on the df containing the last rows, call this new_df. then to drop those rows from the original df you can do: df.drop(new_df.index.get_level_values(1)).  now, you've got the original df in two pieces, which was the original problem.